# Calling one repository's function in another repository | Laravel Repository

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, repository, repository-pattern

I have a Repository that called Business Logic Repo where my functions or methods stores.
And there is a Database Logic Repo that has a method that can interact with the database.

My question is What is the best way to call the functions from Database Logic Repository and use it to the Business Logic Repository.

ex.: on my BusinessLogicRepo I have this function

```
function listSelection($values){
   return $this->model->getSelection($values);
}
```

the getSelection() function is from Database Logic Repository wherein it does the query.

```
function getSelection($tableName, $idField, $nameField){
   $query = DB::table($tableName)->select($idField,$nameField)->get();
   return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In BusinessLogicRepo, you need to bind DatabaseLogicRepository in constructor like this:

```
class BusinessLogicRepo
{

    private $_databaseLogicRepository;

    public function __construct(DatabaseLogicRepository $databaseLogicRepository) 
    {
        $this->_databaseLogicRepository = $databaseLogicRepository;
    }

    public function listSelection($values)
    {
       return $this->_databaseLogicRepository->getSelection($values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the constructor to bind the model to the repository. Because I make my model to a generic one. wherein it can be used by any model.

Comment: In DatabaseLogicRepository you can put the constructor to bind the model.

Answer (score 1):

In your Business Logic Repo just make a constructor call the repository and use it in any function  by $this....

```
class BusinessLogicRepositor extends BaseRepository
{
 public $databaselogicRepo;

 function __construct()
 {
   $this->databaselogicRepo = new DatabaseLogicRepository();
 }
 public function example()
 {
  $data = [
        'name' =>'abc',
        'phone' => '123456'
  ];
  $data_id  = $this->databaselogicRepo->save($data);
 }

}
```